# Why i can't access .ino function from .c file?

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32

*homekit.ino:*

```
//headers
#include "homekit.h"
void setup(){
  //some code
}
void loop(){
  //some code too
}
void message_send(homekit_value_t value){
  //function definition
}
```

*homekit_server_config_t.c:*

```
//headers
#include "homekit.h"

message_send(value);
```

*homekit.h:*

```
#pragma once
extern void message_send(homekit_value_t value);
```

Arduino compiler throws me this error:
`` C:\Users\Sleebu\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_987767\sketch\homekit_server_config_t.c.o:(.data.message+0x58): undefined reference to `message_send' ``

All that i wanna do is to call ino function from c file.
How to fix it? Pls help

Comment: Learn from one of the countless tutorials on how to properly use C/C++ header files.  Then know which you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.ino` file is C++, not C. Rename your other file to `homekit_server_config_t.cpp` so that it’s built as C++ code. C cannot call C++ functions.